front end form with empty asset field and enctype="multipart/form-data" doesn't remove existing asset link
I'm building a front end form to create / edit entries where I also have an asset field. The uploading of files works fine, but when editing an existing entry, I can't remove the current asset (link).
When I don't pass the IDs of the currently linked assets when resaving the entry, the links should disappear. (As described here: https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/reference/field-types/assets.html#development).
So when submitting the form, I see the following in the request (excerpt):
-----------------------------366693930238477068852192657275
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fields[fotos][]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------366693930238477068852192657275
xxx

Since the field with the name is present and has no value, I assume the entry to have an empty field with the name 'fotos' afterwards. But the field still has the asset linked, as before.
When I have already uploaded files and include them with hidden inputs and also upload a new file (as described in the link above), only the new file is linked afterwards.
Interestingly, when I remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from the form tag, an empty file input removes the linked asset. But I can't upload new assets any longer.
Am I doing something wrong?

It seems like this was a bug and was solved in Craft CMS 5.4.7
